# Run Export template from Azure with parameters

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

From a resource in Azure, I can **Export template**.

[image]

I saw those documents:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resources-cli
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resources-powershell

but none of them explain how to run the **Export template**.

How can I run this template to recreate the entire resource group with all resources?
Also, I want to add a parameter related to the job. For example, every resource has to have this job number in the name.

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail?

Answer (score 0):

you could deploy ARM template with powershell, CLI, Azure portal(via REST API), REST API and more. you can check the **How to** [deploy templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell) series of ARM template on MS docs. it's very much detailed.

eg: powershell deployment option with template + parameters

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName ExampleResourceGroup `
  -TemplateFile <path-to-template> `
  -TemplateParameterFile <path-to-parameters>
```